# How to create this "clover" image on Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have this logo I have been playing around in Canva with and I want to recreate it in Illustrator to use. As you can see it is 4 Crescent shaped semi-circles surrounding a center circle to give this "Clover" appearance.

I am having trouble creating the 4 Crescents to fit perfectly around the center circle without cutting or being proportionally unequal.

Any help as to go about recreating this? [image]

(The above image is from Canva, in which I am trying to recreate).

Comment: Colour and a small gap between the shapes aside, this is the Samsonite logo. You might want to think twice about using this for anything that comes close to their business.

Comment: I thought so too initially seeing it, but figured given there is no spacing, different colours and different font of text it should be ok? 

TBH i am quite new to this, this something I am working on at an internship, so any advice and feedback is much appreciated!

Comment: That is a tricky question only a copyright lawyer can fully answer for you. Personally, I wouldn't risk it and try and find another shape to work with.

Comment: The problem is that when you display your logo in black and white only

Comment: This tutorial video shows how to draw the LOGO https://youtu.be/jySMr4kc5Qw
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsDtv.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsDtv.jpg)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this method Sir if it can help you. Im using CS6 Illustrator

1. Create the base circle (first circle)
2. Create the outer circles

   a. Select the path then Copy to back (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>)

   b. Select Scale Tool & then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> to change the center of the copy to the bottom anchor point

   [image]

   b1. Adjust the value to the desired radius (for me I used 200%)
   Note that the radius of second circle will affect the appearance of the  object

   c. Go to Outline view to see the target center which is from the first circle

   [image]

   d. As the path of the bigger circle selected, choose the Rotate tool

   [image]

   d1. Choose Rotate tool

   d2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> then point/click to the center of the first circle

   d3. A pop up menu will appear. Type 90 in the degrees value then press copy.

   d4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to repeat what you have done (do it 2 times)

   [image]
3. Create the Shapes (outline view)

   a. Select all path / all circle

   [image]

   b. Find Shape builder tool or (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>)

   [image]

   c. Select the areas that will be merged in a shape

   [image]

   d. Clean the file (many residual shapes left)
4. Go out of the Outline view (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> again)

   a. (paint / change fill) give shapes temporary colors so you could identify them in layers (still using shape builder tool)

   [image]

   b. Using the select tool adjust to the desired color

Comment: This was super helpful, thank you for taking the time to go through the steps with visual aids! Appreciate the support

Answer (score 1):

Consider that the crescent shaped semi-circles are full circles, with adjacent shapes subtracted in the desired order to create the objective.

Create one circle, then a polar array at 90° rotation for three additional copies. It will be necessary to perform progressive subtraction/difference in an appropriate order for each adjacent circle, which will give you the primary shape.

Create a final circle in the center of the array and subtract that from the total array.

I've couched the solution in general terms, as the task can be accomplished in many different graphics programs, but the specific menu selections and commands will be phrased differently from one to another.

Update: after posting the above recommendation, I discovered a slightly easier method. Create one circle, copy it to the first 90° rotation location and perform the difference/subtraction. The result will be the half-moon shape desired. Keeping the same center of polar rotation, create the three other copies.

I found it easier to use the bitmap from a screen cap of your image as a reference. There are some inaccuracies in the image, but nothing a minor adjustment to the vectors didn't solve. It was also easier to create the center circle and use its center as the polar rotation point, but not include it in the subtraction action until the last sequence.